# Mostrar imagen determinada en PHP guardada en MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
include ("conexion.php");

if(isset($_FILES['img'])){
$nombreImg=$_FILES['img']['name'];
$ruta=$_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
$destino="imagenes/".$nombreImg;
if(copy($ruta,$destino)){
    $sql="INSERT INTO `imagenes`(nombre,ruta) VALUES 
('$nombreImg','$destino')";
    $res=mysqli_query($cn,$sql);
    if($res){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Agregado Correctamente"); 
window.location="index.php";</script>';

    }else{
        die("Error".mysqli_error($cn));
    }

}

}
?>
```

Tengo este codigo y el siguiente formulario para almacenar imagenes en una tabla de MYSQL.

```
<?php
include ("conexion.php");
$sql="SELECT * FROM `imagenes` ";
$res=mysqli_query($cn,$sql);
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insertar Imagen</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Insertar y Mostrar imagen en PHP y MYSQL</h1>
<form action="cargar.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Nombre <input type="file" name="img" ><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Aceptar">
</form>
<hr>
<?php
while ($data=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
echo '<img src="'.$data['ruta'].'" width="200px" height="200px">';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Esta es la tabla en la que se guarda la imagen]

```
while ($data=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
echo '<img src="'.$data['ruta'].'" width="200px" height="200px">';
}
```

Con ese bucle he conseguido sacar todas las imagenes por ruta, pero me gustaria sacar las imagenes por CodImagen y con la descripcion y el nombre de producto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado de varias maneras y no hay manera, a ver si podeis echarme una mano.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

En principio, el método es el miosmo. Si pones el error que te devuelve y el código que estás usando puedo echarle un ojo. Sin verlo es difícil.

Por lo pronto... ¿Le estás dando algún valor a codImagen? si no es normal que no puedas listar por ese campo.

Comment: Como dice @JRCode, el procedimiento es el mismo, solo que en lugar de mandar a traer todos los registros, pides el que quieres con el `WHERE codProducto = 1`